# Play start process running high cpu when started in ruby

Tags: ruby, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, cpu-usage

I'm running on play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_45 and Scala 2.10.0) on Ubuntu.

It just hits 100% straight away, my guess is it's something to do with the stdout/stdin/stderr or similar, but I'm not sure.

Then when using the thing, I get this sort of two minute wait in the application log:

```
2013-12-30 15:53:44,942 - [INFO] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2
Formed query 'DELETE FROM MatchPlayer WHERE mp_id='17';'

2013-12-30 15:55:44,735 - [INFO] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2 
Asked to delete from table MatchPlayer with id 18
```

Here's the ruby code used to launch it:

```
TestServer::start_and_wait(TestConfig::SERVER_PORT)

def TestServer.start_and_wait(port)
    start(port)
    #wait_for_start()
end

def TestServer.start(port)

    # Play blocks, so start this on a new thread
    thread = Thread.new do
    TestConfig.get_logger.info("Starting server on port #{port}")
    output = Util::Process::run_command("play \"start #{port}\"", true)

end

def Process.run_command(command, verbose = false)

    logger = TestConfig::get_logger

    if(verbose)
        logger.info("Ran command '#{command}'")
    end

    Open3.popen3(command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|

        # We don't need stdin
        stdin.close

        # Wait for process to finish and then grab stdout, stderr
        out = stdout.gets
        err = stderr.gets

        stdout.close
        stderr.close

        rc = wait_thr.value.exitstatus

        if(verbose)
            logger.info("Stdout was: \n")
            logger.info("#{out}\n")
            logger.info("Stderr was: \n")
            logger.info("#{err}\n")
            logger.info("Return code was '#{rc}'")
        end

        return ProcessResult.new(command, out, err, rc)

    end

end
```

Comment: Have you verified that the computer is not using the swap? The database is in memory or on file system? it is possible that the database contains a lot of data and does not have correct indexes?

Comment: Yeah, it's in memory. Not sure what you mean by "the swap". I've managed to do a little investigation and turns out the nature of it is quite actually different to what I previously imagined. Will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you try attaching visualvm and profile it to see what it spends your cpu cycles doing? Should give you a pointer to what could be wrong.